# How to use std::enable_if with a condition which itself depends on another condition?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, enable-if

I have a situation where I need to distinguish two overloads, say, `foo`, using `std::enable_if`. The condition given to `std::enable_if` itself depends on a dependent type of the template parameter of `foo`.

What is the best way to express this using `std::enable_if`?

The following test code is what I have so far. I realize there are possibly better ways besides `std::enable_if` to achieve the behavior I want in the test code. However, the following is a simplified version of my use case which itself requires `std::enable_if`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

struct bar
{
  using baz = int;
};

template<class T> struct is_bar : std::false_type {};
template<> struct is_bar<bar> : std::true_type {};

template<class Bar>
struct baz_type
{
  using type = typename Bar::baz;
};


template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_integral<
    typename baz_type<T>::type
  >::value,
  int
>::type
  foo(T x)
{
  return 7;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<
  !is_bar<T>::value,
  int
>::type
  foo(T x)
{
  return 13;
}

int main()
{
  assert(foo(bar()) == 7);
  assert(foo(0) == 13);

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler output:

```
$ g++ --version ; echo ; g++ -std=c++11 repro.cpp 
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


repro.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct baz_type<int>’:
repro.cpp:29:3:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<typename baz_type<Bar>::type>::value, int>::type foo(T) [with T = int]’
repro.cpp:49:3:   required from here
repro.cpp:18:33: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
   using type = typename Bar::baz;
```

This code does not compile because the `enable_if` used in the first overload of `foo` depends on the nested type `T::baz`. Because `int` does not have this nested type, the code is illegal.

What is the correct way to express what I want?

Comment: Can you make `baz_type` an alias template rather than a class template?

Comment: An alternative is to use several `enable_if`s, e.g. using default template arguments. The first should check `is_bar`, then the second can use `baz_type<T>::type`. The Standard mandates that they're evaluated in lexical order.

Comment: @DanielFrey *shrug* Have my upvote. Though I wouldn't consider it very readable, at least not after [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26533335/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I wrote the below on Coliru, @dyp already showed the important part in his comment. The following is what will work and what is, IMHO, quite readable:

```
template<
    class T,
    typename=typename std::enable_if<is_bar<T>::value>::type,
    typename=typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<typename baz_type<T>::type>::value>::type
>
int foo(T x)
{
  return 7;
}

template<
    class T,
    typename=typename std::enable_if<!is_bar<T>::value>::type
>
int foo(T x)
{
  return 13;
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e19a0b5748f154e2)

With C++14, one would use `std::enable_if_t` to make it even shorter.